# Angular : Manual redirect to route

Tags: angular

I just recently started using angular 4 instead of angular.js 1.

I have followed the heroes tutorial to learn about the fundamentals of angular 4 and I am currently using angular's own "RouterModule" from the "@angular/router" package.

In order to implement some authorization for my application I would like to know how to manually redirect to another route, I can not seem to find any useful information about this on the internet.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

### Angular routing : Manual navigation

First you need to import the angular router :

```js
import {Router} from "@angular/router"
```

Then inject it in your component constructor :

```js
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

And finally call the `.navigate` method anywhere you need to "redirect" :

```js
this.router.navigate(['/your-path'])
```

You can also put some parameters on your route, like `user/5` :

```js
this.router.navigate(['/user', 5])
```

Documentation: [Angular official documentaiton](https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero)

Answer (score 11):

Redirection in angularjs 4
Button for event in eg:app.home.html

```
<input type="button" value="clear" (click)="onSubmit()"/>
```

and in home.componant.ts

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import {Router} from '@angular/router';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.home.html',
 })

 export class HomeComponant {
   title = 'Home';
   constructor(
     private router: Router,
    ) {}

  onSubmit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/doctor'])
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

You should inject Router in your constructor like this;

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

then you can do this anywhere you want;

```
this.router.navigate(['/product-list']);
```

Comment: As this is for authoriztion you should also do this inside a router guard.  https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router"

export class YourClass{

   constructor(private router: Router) { }

   YourFunction() {
      this.router.navigate(['/path']);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Angular Redirection manually:** Import `@angular/router`, Inject in `constructor()` then call `this.router.navigate()`.

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
... 
...

constructor(private router: Router) {
  ...
}

onSubmit() {
  ...
  this.router.navigate(['/profile']); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Redirect to another page using function on component.ts file

componene.ts:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router) {}

OnClickFunction()
  {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="col-3">                  
<button (click)="OnClickFunction()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-custom mr-3">Button Name</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
constructor(  public router: Router,) {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => this._onRouteGetParams(params));
}
this.router.navigate(['otherRoute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have enough correct answers for your question but in case your IDE gives you the warning

> Promise returned from navigate is ignored

you may either ignore that warning or use `this.router.navigate(['/your-path']).then()`.