# How to redirect Page in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I'm Trying to redirect one component to another (like page redirect)

[Angular link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

here is my code

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { RoleComponent } from './role/role.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/AppComponent', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'role', component: RoleComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**top-header.component.html**

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Verified</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/role" class="nav-link" href="#">ROLES</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

**AppComponent.html**

```
<div class="container p-md-0">
<app-top-header></app-top-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-main-contain></app-main-contain>
</div>
```

Comment: Please configure routers properly.You haven't mention router for /AppComponent.

Comment: You told about this code ?                                                                 {path: 'AppComponent' , component: AppComponent}, .    When i put this code design display multiple time .

Comment: Instead of forRoot(routes) you just use RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES) for lazy loading and please attach app.module.ts file here.

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopHeaderComponent,
    AlertComponent,
    MainContainComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    RoleComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: Remove  { path: '', redirectTo: '/AppComponent', pathMatch: 'full' }, line and check.

Comment: yes it's working but old component not hide...

Comment: which component is not hide?

Comment: first one which defualt show

Comment: In your application when it is load into the browser by default you have mention bootstrap as app.component on startup then after routing is called you have set if domain path is blank('') then redirect to app.component.ts.that's problem.

Comment: Go through official routing documentation of angular.it will help you.

Comment: Follow the steps from this link, you can thank me later:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133610/angular-4-manual-redirect-to-route?rq=1.

Comment: Here you can a very clear tutorial on how add routing to your existing angular app and how to redirect or change current component - https://shermandigital.com/blog/configure-routing-in-an-angular-cli-project/

Answer (score 28):

You can use `router.navigate` function of the Router class. Just import Router from `@angular/router` and create a object for it in the `constructor(private router: Router)` and use `router.navigate(['/roles']);`

```
import { RoleComponent } from './role/role.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/AppComponent', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'role', component: RoleComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor(private router: Router)
}

functionOnWhichRedirectShouldHappen(){
  this.router.navigate(['/role']);
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Verified</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <button (click)="functionOnWhichRedirectShouldHappen()">ROLES</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: in wiche page ?

Comment: @DhrupalSuthar Check the answer now

Comment: And you can use routerLink too. Use it like  [routerLink]="['/role']"

Answer (score 23):

Your **app-routing.module.ts** is fine. Now, in your component you can do Import *Router* and use it to redirect.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  redirect() {
      this.router.navigate(['role']);
  }

}
```

And in your component.html just call that `redirect()` function

```
<button (click)="redirect()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this path in your `app-routing.module.ts` file so that it can know the path:

```
{ path: 'AppComponent', component: AppComponent }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Suggest you to edit the code with code formatting. For more information on code formatting, refer this meta post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution :

```
  redirectTo() {
    window.history.back()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect your page to another one by adding this to your **app-routing.module.ts**

file :

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'component route name', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'component route name', component: MyComponent },
```

Answer (score -3):

Try below code

You can use Angular $window

```
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Example usage in a contoller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

    LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$window', 'loginSrv', 'notify'];

    function LoginCtrl($window, loginSrv, notify) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.validateUser = function () {
             loginSrv.validateLogin(vm.username, vm.password).then(function (data) {          
                if (data.isValidUser) {    
                    $window.location.href = '/index.html';
                }
                else
                    alert('Login incorrect');
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: The question is related to Angular, not AngularJS which is what your answer uses. The two work quite differently.